# Why is this not working? (Java for loop condition part)

Tags: java, for-loop

```
int cnt = 0, sum = 0;
for(int i = 1; ((i <= 1000) && (i%3 == 0) && (i%5 == 0)); i++){
    if(cnt >= 5)
        break;
    System.out.println(i);
    sum += i;
    cnt++;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

I want to get the first 5 numbers that are divisible by 3 as well as 5 between the range of [1, 1000]. This code does not shows any error but it returns 'sum' and 'cnt' both to it's default values (i.e. 0) and seems to me that it's not entering the for loop.

P.S. I am not advance level programmer. I'm trying this stuff just for exploration, so if any one could explain the actual reason behind this.

Comment: See [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: also do refer to https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp to see the syntax for a for-loop. Your second statement does not return true, so code is not executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you do not understand how a for loop works. `@Silvio Mayolo` and `@experiment unit 1998X` commented some very helpful links. I would encourage you to read through those and get comfortable with them.

In your example, your for loop has a very complex header.

`for(int i = 1; ((i <= 1000) && (i%3 == 0) && (i%5 == 0)); i++){`

Let's break this apart into sections.

- `for` -- this is the keyword that starts the for loop
- `int i = 1;` -- now you have created a variable in your loop. It is an `int` called `i`, and it has a starting value of `1`.
- [`(the termination expression)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) -- If the termination expression returns `false`, then loop stops looping. Let's see how you used it

  - `i <= 1000` -- now you have added a rule --> in order for the for loop to perform a loop, the number `i` must be less than or equal to `1000`. Ok, that is simple enough, you are now going to have at least 1000 valid values for `i` thus far.
  - `i%3 == 0` -- now you have added another rule --> in order for the loop to perform a loop, the number `i` must have no remainder when divided by 3. Unfortunately, that is a problem because your starting value for `i` is `1`, as mentioned earlier, and 1/3 ***DOES have a remainder***. Therefore, the loop stops before it even starts.

This is your problem. If you want to check and see if `i%3 == 0`, you should not put that check inside of your *termination expression*. It should go inside of the enclosing block within the for loop. And the same applies for `i%5 == 0`.

Here is a runnable example to help you understand.

```java
public class SOQ_20220516
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   
      int cnt = 0;
      int sum = 0;
   
      for(int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
      {
         if(cnt >= 5)
         {
            break;
         }
      
         if ((i%3 == 0) && (i%5 == 0))
         {
         
            System.out.println(i);
            sum += i;
            cnt++;
         
         }
      }
   
      System.out.println(sum);
      System.out.println(cnt);
   
   }

}
```

Comment: You are correct, I have fixed my mistake

Comment: Very much understood! Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 0):

public class SOQ_20220516
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

```
  int cnt = 0;
  int sum = 0;

  for(int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
  {
     if(cnt >= 5)
     {
        break;
     }
  
     if ((i%3 == 0) && (i%5 == 0))
     {
     
        System.out.println(i);
        sum += i;
        cnt++;
     
     }
  }

  System.out.println(sum);
  System.out.println(cnt);
```

}

}

> Blockquote

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).